# Hangfire Integration With AspNet Core 3.1 Console Application DI Error Object does not match target type

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, console-application, hangfire

I am trying to use Hangfire.Core 1.7.11 in my console application but I've got stuck with the DI container. The following error is shown:

> "ExceptionType":"System.Reflection.TargetException","ExceptionMessage":"Object
>   does not match target
>   type.","ExceptionDetails":"System.Reflection.TargetException: Object
>   does not match target type.
>
> **Error on the line** BackgroundJob.Enqueue(a => a.UpdateDB());

Here's what I've tried:

```
    class Program
    {
        private static IServiceProvider _serviceProvider { get; set; }
        private static ServiceCollection _service { get; set; }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
            string dd = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
            var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()).AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true);
            var _config = builder.Build();
            string bgConnString = _config.GetSection("smsDBConnection:bgDBCon").Value;
            string smsConnString = _config.GetSection("smsDBConnection:smsDBCon").Value;

            RegisterServices(_config);
            var scope = _serviceProvider.CreateScope();


            // var myservice = new ServiceCollection();
            //  var rr = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.UseActivator(new ContainerJobActivator(_serviceProvider));



            GlobalConfiguration.Configuration
                .SetDataCompatibilityLevel(CompatibilityLevel.Version_170)
    .UseSimpleAssemblyNameTypeSerializer()
    .UseRecommendedSerializerSettings()
    .UseSqlServerStorage(bgConnString, new SqlServerStorageOptions
    {
        CommandBatchMaxTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5),
        SlidingInvisibilityTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5),
        QueuePollInterval = TimeSpan.Zero,
        UseRecommendedIsolationLevel = true,
        UsePageLocksOnDequeue = true,
        DisableGlobalLocks = true
    }).UseActivator(new ContainerJobActivator(_service));

            using (var bgpServer = new BackgroundJobServer())
            {
                BackgroundJob.Enqueue<Activity>(a => a.UpdateDB());
                Console.WriteLine("background job registered");
                Console.WriteLine("background job for DB registered");
                //  DisposeServices();
                Console.ReadLine();
            }

        }


        private static void RegisterServices(IConfigurationRoot configurationRoot)
        {
            string conString = configurationRoot.GetSection("smsDBConnection:smsDBCon").Value;
            _service = new ServiceCollection();
            _service.AddDbContextPool<NeuroDBContext>(options =>
            {
                options.UseSqlServer(conString);
            });


            // _service.AddScoped<IActivity, Activity>();
            // _service.AddScoped<Activity>();

            _serviceProvider = _service.BuildServiceProvider(true);
        }

        private static void DisposeServices()
        {
            if (_serviceProvider == null)
            {
                return;
            }
            if (_serviceProvider is IDisposable)
            {
                ((IDisposable)_serviceProvider).Dispose();
            }
        }


    }
```

My activity class:

```
public class Activity : IActivity
    {
        private NeuroDBContext _context { get; }
        public Activity(NeuroDBContext neuroDBContext)
        {
            _context = neuroDBContext;
        }

        public void UpdateDB()
        {
            var d = _context.SubscriberDevicePairing.Skip(0).Take(5);
            foreach (var item in d)
            {
                item.IsRenew = true;
            }
            _context.UpdateRange(d);
            _context.SaveChanges();

        }
    }
```

My activator class:

```
public  class ContainerJobActivator: JobActivator
    {
        private IServiceCollection _container;

        public ContainerJobActivator(ServiceCollection container)
        {
            _container = container;
        }



        public override object ActivateJob(Type type)
        {
            if (!_container.Any(a => a.ServiceType == type))
            {
                _container.AddScoped(type);
            }
            return _container;

        }
```

Please help me. Thanks.

Comment: From the looks of it, you will need to find a way to initialize _context of your Activity class inside Update() if I am not mistaken (or pass it to Update as an argument). [See documentation](https://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/background-methods/passing-dependencies.html)

Comment: @Jawad Initially I thought to initialize DBContext inside the Activity Class but i have also other complex requirements where I want to use DI for initializations of my objects.Does hangfire.core does not support in-built ,net core DI?